# Why won't my video show unless I click the progress bar in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a short mp4 embedded in a PowerPoint presentation. It's set to loop indefinitely and start when the slide comes up, but the video doesn't show. If I mouse over the progress bar, it shows it repeating in a loop, but the window is black. If I click somewhere on the progress bar, it plays through once, then the bar loops again with the video stuck on the last frame of video. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colin Zheng, ex-MS engineer, wrote a pretty good blog article on this matter. You can find it [here](http://www.colinzheng.com/?p=36).

**The TL;DR of the article**:

Apparently, Powerpoint doesn't use a fully-fledged media player, but a stripped down version of WMP 6 (yeah, you read that right). So any advanced technologies may not be compatible with it. You have three options:

```
Option 1: Convert videos to .wmv and disable Hardware Acceleration

Option 2: Convert videos to .mpg using QuicktimePro

Option 3: Embed the real Windows Media Player
```

But that still doesn't explain why cutting the first and last microseconds of you video works though...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure WHY this works, but editing the start/stop times to be a couple ms from the ends seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: MS's official [advice](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982947) is to use the Powerpoint viewer. Thanks for nothing Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Power point doesn't supprt mp4 video file. You have to convert it to wmv. You can convert it online also, it's free. You can check it on google.